How to write a footnote for a source in Arabic?
Currently, my footnote looks like this:

محمد سهيل طقوشi, تاريخ العثمانيين من قيام الدولة إلى الإنقلاب على الخلافةi (Beirut: دار النفائس لبنانi, 2013), p.113.

However, there are a two problems:

I cannot italicize the title
the right-to-left system is messing up the order of words (thats why I had to put an “i” at the end of each Arabic phrase)

What do people normally do in that situation? Should I transliterate it?

Italics are specific to Latin scripts. Unlike the roman type, which was modelled after Roman inscriptions, in which the letters were upright and unconnected, cursive or italic scripts were modelled after handwriting and the letters connected (which speeds up writing in handwriting). The use of italic fonts to show emphasis within roman text was developed in the sixteenth century.
Non-Latin scripts such as Arabic, Chinese etc. do not have italic variants, so we cannot use italics for emphasis, titles, etc.
Following the CMOS, you give Arabic titles or sources in the original with a translation behind the original in square brackets. Here is an example using Chinese (the source also gives examples for footnotes etc.):

Abe, Yoshio 阿部善雄, and Hideo Kaneko 金子英生.  Saigo no "Nihonjin" : Asakawa Kan'Ichi no shōgai 最後の「日本人」 : 朝河貫一の生涯 [The last 'Japanese': Life of Kan'ichi Asakawa]. Tōkyō: Iwanami Shoten, 1983.

I have no idea why you should need to put an i behind the Arabic text. Maybe you need to ask about that in a forum for Arabic or for the texteditor that you use. There is https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/, which has a few questions about Arabic. There is also r/learn_arabic

Minor correction: Italics aren't specific to Latin script, they're also used in Cyrilic and Greek script, so let's say European, or Phoenician-based scripts. Your point that they aren't a thing outside of this group stands.

@Ben +1. Aside: If a question is worth answering, it is worth upvoting. Not that I have any questions, but it doesn't cost you anything.
